# Why can't I use git rm to delete all files except of a specific file type?

Tags: git, zsh

I want to delete all files in the current directory and its subdirectories that are not of the file type `*.scss`.

However, I keep getting an error:

```
$ git rm -r !(*.scss)
#=> zsh: number expected
```

What is the correct way of doing this? Why is the command failing?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320895/remove-and-ignore-all-files-that-have-an-extension-from-a-git-repository

Comment: That question is about removing all files *with* the extension. I want to remove all files *except* those with the extension.

Comment: @user3574603 : According to the man-page, the pattern `!(....)` requires that the _KSH_GLOB_ option is set. If you set `setopt extendedglob`, you can use the pattern `(^(*.scss))`.

Comment: @user3574603 : But *if* you prefer to go by `setopt ksh_glob`, have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527704/why-cant-i-use-single-pattern-in-zsh-even-after-i-turn-on-kshglob) to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is a special character for shells, it manipulates command history, so you need to screen it using backslash or quotes. Also you need colon. Experiment with `ls-files` a bit, something like

```
git ls-files \* ':!*.scss'
```

and then remove the files with

```
git rm \* ':!*.scss'
```

Also please be warned that `git rm -r` removes directories recursively with a good chance to remove `*.scss` files in them.