# How to delete git files locally without removing them from the remote repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I don't have a lot of disk space on my laptop but the GitLab repository I'm working on with my team contains large mkv files (that I don't personally need or care about). I want to delete only those mkv files from my local repository without it effecting the remote repository. Ideally I also don't want those files to show up every time I pull from the repository either.

I'm new to git/gitLab but from my limited understanding I was thinking maybe a .gitignore file might work but I'm not very familiar with them and I'm not sure how/if that would work. Would this be a viable solution or is there a better way? Thanks for any advise!

Comment: [Remove and ignore all files that have an extension from a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320895/remove-and-ignore-all-files-that-have-an-extension-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: What you need to look at is sparse checkouts. Gitignore won't help as that only prevent `add` and similar command from adding the files to begin with, once you've started to track them, however, gitignore is not used for those files.